# More columns in GNOME 3 app menu

Tags: gnome-shell

I would like to be able to show more columns since a lot of lateral space is lost. Any ideas on how to do this?

[image: Apps aplication menu screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use a [GNOME Shell extension](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75530/how-do-i-install-and-manage-gnome-shell-extensions) called "[More columns in applications view](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1305/more-columns-in-applications-view/)".

This extension lets you

> Set the number of columns in the "applications" view (by default, the maximum is only 6)
>   [image]

---

Another similar extension is "[Application View Columns](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/2159/application-view-columns/)" (officially supports GNOME Shell version 3.30 currently). It lets you

> Set the number of columns in the Applications Overview. Controlled by a slider in the system menu with a switch for increasing compactness for up to 12 columns.
>   [image]